# Matlab error while running

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement the following code in Matlab:

```
v0=eps;
t0=0; tf=10;
[t,v]=ode45(@const_pow, [t0 tf], v0);
```

And the const_pow function is:

```
function f=const_pow(t,v)
   f=(P/v-F0-c*v^2)/m; 
end
```

While I am running the program, the following error shows up:

```
 Error using ==> odearguments at 103

CONST_POW returns a vector of length 0, but the length of initial 
conditions vector is 1. The vector returned by CONST_POW and the   
initial conditions vector must have the same number of elements.
```

Any suggestions on where the error might be?

Comment: Is that the whole of your `const_pow` function? You haven't defined half the variables that go into it, and you're not using `t`.

Comment: All the variables r defined globally. I have provided all d variables data in the main function itself. f is basically dv/dt (acceleration)

Comment: Globals are generally a bad idea, and also you can't access them inside a function unless you declare them global **in that function**.  See answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, you're defining some variables globally.  In order to access them inside `const_pow`, you need to tell that function to use the global variables, e.g.:

```
function f=const_pow(t,v)
   global P F0 c m
   f=(P/v-F0-c*v^2)/m; 
end
```

Without doing this, the function will not touch the global variables (this is to stop you accidentally changing their values).  For example:

```
function f=const_pow(t,v)
   global P F0 c
   m = 23.7; % this does not change the global value of m
   f=(P/v-F0-c*v^2)/m; 
end
```

An alternative to passing a number of variables without using globals is to define a structure with your required data:

```
data.P = % initial values
data.F0 = 
data.c = 
data.m =
```

This also gives you a little more flexibility if there is more than one set of options.  Or, you could pass the variables in directly. To do this with `ode45`, you would need to [parameterize](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) the function using an anonymous function:

```
function f=const_pow(t,v,P,F0,c,m)
    % and so on
end
```

With `P,F0,c,m` pre-defined:

```
odefun = @(t,v) const_pow(t,v,P,F0,c,m); % anonymous function
```

Then:

```
[t,v]=ode45(odefun, [t0 tf], v0);
```

Comment: Hi, I have put the global variables inside the const_pow function too function f=const_pow(t,v)
global P c F0 m 
f=(P/v-F0-c*v^2)/m; 
end

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside `const_pow` and doublecheck that `f` is coming out as you'd expect. A possible explanation is that one of your global variables is empty, resulting in `f` being passed back as empty. I still don't understand why you're not using `t` at all in that function.